# Community Wiki Etiquette

Tags: discussion, community-wiki

Is it proper for to mark an "accepted answer" for a community wiki question.

On the one hand, it seems okay to do as the site allows it.  On the other hand, we seem to be marking questions  that have no single right answer as community wikis.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The system seems to encourage marking at least one answer as accepted, including giving reminders to the author. I think either way is fine.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  It is very appropriate when one answer is a good candidate for the best answer to read just after the question.  This is likely to be the case where the questioner is fishing for opinions on some issue, typically here on meta, and finds one answer that seems to sum up the matter satisfactorily.

It's tricky in the case of [big-list] questions, but here, if someone has made the effort to give some kind of overview of the possible answers, it can be appropriate.