# Why is this subjective question admissible?

Tags: discussion

I'm not sure why this question isn't severely down-voted:

[Most memorable CS paper titles](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/27143/most-memorable-cs-paper-titles)

It is clearly an opinion question soliciting lists of answers, instead of a single canonical answer.  From my understanding, this is not reflective of the standards across the stack exchange.  Is this community more open to soliciting such questions?  Is there something of value to the community that can be gained from this particular  question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. There is nothing wrong per se with questions which don't have a single answer. Where have you got that idea? If you mean [big-list](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/big-list) questions then yes, we allow them, for more information have a look at [On the efficacy of "Big List" questions](https://cstheory.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2865/on-the-efficacy-of-big-list-questions)
2. Yes, as a research oriented site we have allowed things that might be problematic on other sites like SO. If you want a simple guide, we follow MO model than SO model. The reason is simple: we started the site with the goal of making something similar to MO for TCS, the communities are similar, etc. So if it is OK on MO it is probably OK here. Other SE sites don't matter that much for our policy decisions.
3. See also [Good subjective, bad subjective](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/). There is nothing wrong with asking *good* subjective questions.

Comment: Good answer!  I guess research level questions are by nature more open ended.  I didn't realize SE sites had different models to emulate.  I thought SO was the only model to emulate.